# What does the final episode of Ted Lasso mean? (S03E12) (spoilers!)

Tags: ted-lasso

The final scene ends with a zoom-in on Ted’s face as he smiles vaguely into the camera while the sound (the world as he hears it?) turns into a cacophony of echoing sounds and voices. Earlier, on the plane, he had read Michael Pollan's "How to Change Your Mind: The New Science of Psychedelics". Psychedelics already played a part in the Sunflower episode.

Now here is the frightening question: Did the writers pull a "It was all in his head"-plot device on us? Did Ted use psychedelics to get over his marital problems and dream up the whole Richmond FC world? Were his repeated anxiety attacks withdrawal symptoms? OR does Ted use drugs from now on to be content with his new old life? That would be an ever sadder ending imho.

Comment: I honestly think you're over-reading it… by about a mile. Why can't he just be happy to be home, coaching junior soccer?

Answer (score 2):

> What does the final episode of *Ted Lasso* mean?

To the best of my knowledge, it simply means that Ted is content with his new life back in Kansas, teaching Henry. There's no need to read anything further into it, and virtually no evidence to support your darker interpretation.

> Did the writers pull a "It was all in his head"-plot device on us?

Almost certainly not. If the whole series *was* just Ted's hallucination, one would expect a much more explicit confirmation than the oblique hints you refer to in your queston (see the final episode of *[Newhart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newhart#%22The_Last_Newhart%22)* for a famous example). Without such confirmation, we should assume that everything seen on screen actually happened. Note that when Ted was on psychedelics in "Sunflowers", his hallucinations primarily manifested as animations rather than live-action.

> Did Ted use psychedelics to get over his marital problems and dream up the whole Richmond FC world?

Unlikely. In addition to the above, when Ted took psychedelics in "Sunflowers", it is at the very least strongly implied that he has never done so before. Not to mention that Ted never actually gets over his marital problems entirely - as late as "We'll Never Have Paris", he's upset about the possibility of Michelle re-marrying. So if he *was* taking psychedelics to get over it, it didn't work.

> Were his repeated anxiety attacks withdrawal symptoms?

[Psychedelic drugs are not addictive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychedelic_drug#Potential_adverse_effects) and therefore do not have withdrawal symptoms. So, no.

> Or does Ted use drugs from now on to be content with his new old life?

Yet again, there is no evidence to support this.